# Ultisnips stopped working this morning

Tags: macvim, plugin-ultisnips

I've been using Vim for about a year now (so still a newbie), but this morning UltiSnips stopped working for me. Any help would be really appreciated!

When I run `:UltiSnipsEdit!` the console returns `E492: Not an editor command`. However what's weird is that I can still run `:h UltiSnips` and I get the help menu. Moreover, UltiSnips shows up twice under `:scriptnames` as

```
~/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/plugin/UltiSnips.vim
~/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/after/plugin/UltiSnips_after.vim
```

Other relevant info - I am running MacVim. Below is a minimum `.vimrc` which shows this error:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"
let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

Comment: Did you make any changes to vim or your .vimrc recently?

Comment: Not recently, no

Comment: That you get E492 suggests [this line](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/8ff301c651d6df806c0f9305273a6c62a693bc48/plugin/UltiSnips.vim#L44) has issues. what is the output of `:verbose command UltiSnipsEdit` ?

Comment: I get `No user-defined commands found`